# Stranger lines in perspective mode (Cavity)

Tags: modeling

Strange lines are appearing when I'm in perspective mode. In the orthogonal view it doesn't happen. Apparently it's linked to the cavity and backface culling settings. Does anyone know what could be going on?

I'm using Blender 3.5.0

[image]
Cavity ON and Backface Culling OFF

[image]
Cavity OFF and Backface Culling OFF

[image]
Cavity OFF and Backface Culling ON

Comment: That looks as if it could be a graphics driver issue. Try updating your drivers?

Comment: Could _possibly_ be View > Clipping range ?  Symptom makes sense. Not quite a typical look, though.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.